# g++ compiler: compilation terminated

Tags: c++, gcc, compilation, g++, cygwin

I have a very simple program:

```
// hello.cpp
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main() {
   cout << "Hello, world!" << endl;
   return 0;
}
```

When I used Command Prompt (Windows) and type:

```
g++ -o hello hello.cpp
```

I got this error:

```
In file included from /usr/include/wchar.h:6:0,
                 from /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/4.9.2/include/c++/cwchar:44,

                 from /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/4.9.2/include/c++/bits/posty pes.h:40,
                 from /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/4.9.2/include/c++/iosfwd:40,

                 from /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/4.9.2/include/c++/ios:38,
                 from /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/4.9.2/include/c++/ostream:38 ,
                 from /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/4.9.2/include/c++/iostream:3 9,
                 from hello.cpp:2: /usr/include/sys/reent.h:14:20: fatal error: stddef.h: No such file or directory

 #include <stddef.h>
                    ^ compilation terminated.
```

Can anyone solve this problem? I try gcc and everything works fine. It seems that g++ is having some problems. My g++ version is 4.9.2

Comment: I think this problem indicates a version mismatch between gcc and g++. Can you verify that they are both the same version?

Comment: Your cygwin installation looks broken

Comment: my gcc version is 4.9.3. Do they have to be in the same version ?

Comment: This might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19642787/netbeans-and-c-installation

Comment: Thank you, I will try to reinstall g++ and gcc again.

Comment: There's an exact dupe with no answers at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31600600/c-g-compilation-error-stddef-h-no-such-file-or-directory and I can't seem to find another dupe with a good answer.

Answer (score 2):

I hope you are working on Linux.

Try installing build-essentials like

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential
```

Even if it did not work then you may have to install libc6-dev.